# Queries timeout. How to free RAM in Cloud SQL Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-sql

I run nightly jobs that have quite a few long-lasting memory-heavy queries in Cloud SQL Postgres instance (PostgreSQL 12.11 with 12 CPUs and 40GB Memory).
The workload and the amount of data increased lately and i started seeing issues with the db more and more often, where nightly jobs(when db is under the most load) would run forever and never succeed or timeout. As I understand its because of the memory usage (also seeing this is Total memory usage section the memory reaches 100% capacity during the peak hours).
[image]
The only thing that helps is restart, which frees the memory, but it's an emergency short-term fix.
From the database configs, I have these set:

increased work_mem to 400Mb = 1% of RAM (1-5% recommended) Should I increase/decrease it?

increased maintenance_work_mem 4GB = 10% of RAM (10-20% recommended)

shared_buffers = 13.5GB (default)

How can I configure the instance to account for the load without having to increase recourses? Maybe there is a way to somehow free RAM without having to restart the instance?
Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Have you checked this documentation [Optimize High Memory Usage](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/optimize-high-memory-usage)?

Comment: Tune your queries, which you should start by looking at the `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` for them.  If you can make them run faster, they will be holding onto their memory for less time.  You might be able to make them choose a less memory intensive plan as well.

Comment: This is probably not primarily a memory problem. If you don't have enough resources or good enough plans to complete your queries as fast as they come in, and don't have an effective way to limit entry (like a reasonable max_connections or a connection pool) then queries will come in faster than they finish and build up until something breaks.  In this case the thing that breaks is memory, but that doesn't mean more memory will solve the problem--it might just delay the inevitable a bit longer.

Comment: This is not material for a Stackoverflow question. You need to hire someone who can help you tune your workload.

Comment: @ChristianPaulAndaya thank you for the link, i did most of what is suggested there. Will do over once more.

Comment: @jjanes thank you for your reply, I now also think this may not be a memory only issue. Will try to analyse further

Comment: You may contact [Google Cloud Support](https://cloud.google.com/support-hub) to further investigate your project.